# Android Wear Watch Face - Wake Screen Programmatically

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wake-lock, android-wear-data-api

I am receiving a message using the `MessageApi`. I now need to wake the wearable's screen programmatically from the `onMessageReceived()` event. How do I do this?

I've tried using `PowerManager` with this code:

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
wakeLock.acquire();
```

which does nothing to wake the watchface

Comment: Go through this:-  https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html

Comment: Thanks, but how do I apply this to a watchface service in the `onMessageReceived` event?

Comment: The code you need is in the link that Ram posted. You'll use the snippet from the second section (Keep the CPU on), but to turn on the screen on you'll use the PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK constant.

Comment: I've just tried this with no end. See edit above